# how to call table td value into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table td for update and delete the database, and i want to call my td into javascript. i've been try the code below, but i get the undefined value. how can i call my td into javascript ?

here my td code

```
<td class="action">
<div class="hidden-phone visible-desktop btn-group">
    <form class="action" action="/news/{{$news_data->id}}" method="post">
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-info" type="button" onclick="window.location='/news/{{ $news_data->id }}/edit'">
            <i class="icon-edit bigger-120"></i>
        </button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" id="delete" name="delete" href="#confirm-delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete">
            <i class="icon-trash bigger-120"></i>
        </button>

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value={{csrf_token() }}>

        <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Confirmation</h4>
            </div>  
            <div class="modal-body">
                <label><p id="id"></p>Are You Sure Want To Delete</label>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-danger" id="delete" type="button">Delete</button>
                    <a data-handler="1" class="btn btn-small" data-dismiss="modal" >
                    <i class="icon-remove"></i> Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    </form> 
</div> </td>
```

and here the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#category_id').on('change', function(e){
            var id_category = e.target.value;
            $.get('{{ url('news/getid')}}/'+id_category, function(data){
                console.log(id_category);
                console.log(data);
                $('#news_data').empty();
                $.each(data, function(index, element){
                    $('#news_data').append("<tr><td>"+element.title+"</td><td>"+element.file+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+element.content+"</td><td>"+element.like+"</td><td>"+element.view+"</td><td>"+find('.action') +"</td></tr>");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean "call my td into javascript"? tds just exist. they can't "call into" anything. plus, nowhere in your code do you have a `id="category"id"`, so there's nothing for the `.on` to attach to.

Comment: i want to call my td value into this code `<td>"+find('.action') +"</td>`. how can i call it ?
the `$('#category_id')` is my id of my dropdown, not the td.